# Error 'Printer Settings could not be saved' after driver upload (Samba)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing, printer, samba

When I upload driver to Samba, I often get the message "Printer Properties" - "Printer settings could not be saved.  Operation could not be completed (error 0x0000007a)".

Since driver seems to be correctly uploaded to my Samba 3.6.27 server, I do not understand what is the point of this error message.  I also manage to change default configuration of the printer by using the contextual properties dialog (which change on driver upload).

Could you explain what is the actual consequence of the error?  What i can do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is risen on driver change, as the old configuration does not fit the new configuration fields.

The easy solution is to reopen the printer properties dialog, and save th econfiguration using the new 'printer preferences' dialog.